# Eclipse: Render custom annotation with strikethrough text

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, annotations

In Eclipse, how can I render a custom annotation with strikeout text (such as `@Deprecated`)? Do I need to develop my own plugin to do this or is there any option in the Eclipse preferences? I checked my IDE, but obviously I can only define how annotations like `@Deprecated` are being rendered in general.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is using strikeout text for marking depracated classes and other elements. If you don't want to use `@Deprecated` for your annotation, the only way I can see is creating your own plugin, where you can use `java.util.Formatter` class, where there is `format()` method, which is converting text into the string of format u can set up by yourself (or `printf()` method, which is printing formatted string).

You can read about that in the `java.util.formatter` tutorial like this one: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html